# Powershell - Include subfolders in Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

Alright, one more powershell question.

This script moves files into a folder based on the first part of their file name. I have now run into the issue that the folder they are ultimately being moved to are nested in a top folder, so:

"Main Folder" -> "X0" -> "X00000" So if I have X0897, in needs to look into the subfolder of the main folder, "X0", for the subfolder of "X0" that is named "X0897".

The script has to be able to look in the "Main Folder", then look into the subfolders for the "X00000".

Is this something done using recurse? Am I on the right path here? Do I need to drop GetChild?

```
# First, we retrieve a list of files where
# $sDir = Source Directory
$sDir = "N:\USERS\Username\General\Test1\"

# Generate a list of all files in source directory
$Files = (Get-ChildItem -recurse?? $sDir)

# $tDir = Root Target Directory (setting the directory the files are to be moved to)
$tDir = "N:\USERS\User\General\Test\"

# Loop through the list of file names
foreach($File in $Files)
{
# $wFile is set as the variable for our working file name
$wFile = $File.BaseName

# This command splits the working file name to extract the file number from the first part of the filename (nFile)
$nFile = $wFile.Split(' ')[0]


# dFold = the final destination folder of the file in the format of \\drive\folder\SubFolder\    
$dFold = "$tDir$nFile"

# Tests if the destination folder exists
if(Test-Path $dFold -PathType Container)
  {
  # If the folder exists then we move the file
  Copy-Item -Path $sDir$File -Destination $dFold

  # This denotes where the file has been moved to        
  Write-Host $File "Was Moved to:" $dFold
  Write-Host
  }
  # If a folder for the file number does not exist it will not be moved!
  else 
  {
  # This tells you if the file was not moved
  Write-Host $File "Was not moved!"
  }

}
```

Comment: Will the subfolder always be the first two characters of the file name?

Comment: It looks like the first subfolder will always be the first three characters of the filename. So if the file is "X123456", the folder structure would be Main Folder -> X12 -> X123456.



I don't know if it matters, but sometimes the first three will include a dash. So a file name might be X-1234, and the sub folder would read X-1. In some cases it the dash could be at the end, ie: X1- (if the filename was X1-123)

Comment: Wait, so if the file name starts with X0897 then it needs to be copied to `N:\Users\User\General\Test\X0\X0897`? Or does it get copied into `N:\Users\User\General\Test\X0\X00000\X0897`?

Comment: N:\Users\User\General\Test\X0\X0897

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have it:

```
$targetFolder = '{0}{1}\{2}' -f $tDir, $nFile.SubString(0,3), $nFile
```

Comment: No dice. I changed it in lieu of dFold = "$tDir$nFile" (I am assuming that is the intent).

Comment: The intent is that $targetFolder will hold the path to the folder where the file should be copied. So for a file that begins with X123456 $targetFolder would hold C:\Users\User\General\Test\X12\X123456

Comment: That makes sense. Essentially $targetFolder is like $dFold, but it's actually specifying the subfolders?

Edit: I realized what I was doing wrong. It works perfect, thank you!